# Notation for a composite function with the same function

Tags: notation

If I have some composite function $g$, defined as $$g(x)=(k\:\circ\:k\:\circ\:...\:\circ\:k)$$ where $k(x)$ is essentially put into itself $n$ times, is there any compact notation I could express $g(x)$ with?

Comment: One common usage for iterated computations is to write $g(x) = k^n(x)$, acknowledging that this would normally be ambiguous but hopefully clear from the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $k^n(x)$ mentioned in comments is probably the most common. Some people use $k^{(n)}(x)$ and I have also seen $k^{\circ n}(x)$. The last is not as common as the others, but is arguably the clearest of the three so as to distinguish from other possible meanings: $k^n$ could be understood as the $n$th power, and $k^{(n)}$ could mean  the rising factorial or the $n$th derivative!

Wikipedia on [Iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) mentions two more: $k^{[n]}(x)$ and $\:{}^n\!k(x)$. I think they are rare, and would not recommend using them.

If $k^n(x)$ is clear enough in your context, you can use it. Otherwise, to be clear, use $k^{\circ n}(x)$.